# matlab: delete the last row in excel

Tags: excel, matlab, delete-row

I have an excel file with contents and background color,

something like the first row:
[image]

I want to delete all the contents in the first row, there is a command that do that?

**UPDATE:**

I succeeded to delete the cells of A3:I3:

```
esh.Range('A1:I1').value = [];
```

I tried to color the J1 cell by white, but it let me the cell of J2 and I need to get the cell of J3.

so I need to color J1 by 'NoFill'.

how can I do that?

I have to say that **I always want to delete the last row in the file (*the example doesn't show that but always the last line*)**

**you can assume I have the range/number_of_the_row that I want to delete**

```
e = actxserver ('Excel.Application'); %# open Activex server
ewb = e.Workbooks.Open(filename); %# open the file
esh = ewb.ActiveSheet;
clr = [255 255 255] * [1 256 256^2]';
esh.Range('A1:I1').value = [];
esh.Range('J1:J1').Interior.Color = clr;
set(e, 'DisplayAlerts', 0); % Stop dialog!
xlWorkbookNormal = excelWorkbook; %# it's the Excel constant, not sure how to pass it other way
ewb.SaveAs(filename, xlWorkbookNormal)
ewb.Close(false)
e.Quit
e.delete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
esh.Range(J1).interior.ColorIndex = 0;
```